# IF, AND, ELSE functions

Tags: function, math, google-sheets, data-conversion

I am required to make a spreadsheet that can convert from one unit to another. In one cell, the quantity is listed. In the next, the source unit. Then, the final unit. Lastly, the result. I need to find a way to code, in a single line/cell, a way to calculate the results. I was thinking of simply using a function that says, for example:

`"IF(B2="millimeter"), AND(C2="centimeter", THEN(*this cell*=A2/10), ELSE, IF(B2-"...."),`...etc".

The teacher has indicated that I cannot use any more than one cell for the calculation.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach. Do you have any questions in particular?

Comment: That solution doesn't scale too well though. For the addition of each new unit, you'll need to add n-1 conditions.

Comment: @pnuts that's an option!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responding so quickly. I ended up figuring it out. I did it for the case of millimeters and centimeters for now. I used the following function:

=IF(AND(B2="millimeter",C2="centimeter")=TRUE, A2/10, IF(AND(B2="centimeter",C2="millimeter")=TRUE, A2*10, IF((B2=C2),"VALUES ARE IDENTICAL...","UNITS NOT RECOGNIZED")))

Comment: If you worked it out and you're happy with this solution, be sure to mark your own answer as correct when you can!

Answer (score 1):

Would not be appreciated by your teacher, but one *might* try:

```
= hyperlink("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A2&B2&C2)
```

Comment: You,sir, are an evil genius.